# Why was my edit changing the asp-classic tag to asp.net rejected?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I had suggested the following edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2919761

I think my edit is appropriate because the question relates to ASP.NET and certainly not classic ASP.

I don't have any problem with its rejection. I just want to know if I have done anything wrong. If so, then just let me know what I take care about before suggesting any edit?

Comment: @Bart Thx for the edit i will take care of this from the next time

Comment: @Bart only one thing .. i dont have any problem with edit rejection so i have chose title "Have i done anything wrong" but with current title it looks like i have problem with rejection and i am asking why it got rejected ??

Comment: I think it's still fairly neutral. So I would not really worry about it. Feel free to change it though if you like.

Comment: It doesn't imply you disagree, "Why is the sky blue" doesn't imply that I think the sky shouldn't be

Comment: I'm guessing they rejected it because they don't have a clue about the edit being correct or not because they don't know the technology. They should have skipped it instead.

Comment: @RichardTingle It could be _red_...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I think you were right in editing**.

But some reviewers find tag changes `too minor` and reject them which is **wrong**. This should not be done this way. I even supported the separate queue for retag reviews. As it is important to retag, it helps in filtering posts.

I have retagged that question.

Comment: Although all the rejects are for "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." rather than "too minor"

Comment: Yes, in this case. but usually I observed retags were reject as too minor

Comment: but tags helps a lot as most users will look for new question in their expertise area so it will be much helpful if you have right tags attached with your question

Comment: @Dhaval yes, even I search using tags and that is really helpful to filter out.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Updating tags are a great way for the question to pop into the right queue where it will get the views it needs - and at the same time probably one of the ways that the site is optimized to work with search engines. I would think that correcting tags is certainly not too minor a change if appropriate.

Comment: @Fluffeh yes... retag is as important as edit. Even I am in favor of retag seperate queue for review.

Comment: Separate review for retag only edit is just needless since suggested edit review does the same. Additional review, additional badges, additional complains etc..

Comment: So the big question - is there any _official_ stance on whether all retags should be rejected or not?  It's ridiculous that cleaning up tags half the time gets your suggested edit rejected.